# Stroke Dash Interpolation Sample Code Not Working

Tags: html, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to use [Mike Bostock’s Block 5649592](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592#index.html) as an example to draw stroke-dash interpolation.

I copied his code from index.html example into an html file on my local computer, and it is not presenting anything when I open the html file. Does anyone know what's happening here? Am I missing anything here?

I am copying his code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<style>

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

</style>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var points = [
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100],
  [780, 300],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
];

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);

svg.append("path")
    .style("stroke", "#ddd")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "4,4")
    .attr("d", line);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", line)
    .call(transition);

function transition(path) {
  path.transition()
      .duration(7500)
      .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
      .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).call(transition); });
}

function tweenDash() {
  var l = this.getTotalLength(),
      i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
  return function(t) { return i(t); };
}

</script>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Please see my answer post below. Kudos to BJK!

Comment: Since I'm pretty sure you didn't download the library, provide an online reference to D3: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Although not nice, that shouldn't be the issue! See [*"Can I change all my http:// links to just //?"*](/q/4831741) and https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/.

Comment: @altocumulus Yes, you are correct, I was careless in my comment: I just skimmed through the code and though that that was a absolute path. In my (tyred) mynd I read `"/d3.v3.min.js"`.

Comment: Thank you for your discussion. As @ altocumulus says, the missing https is probably not the issue. I changed it to what @ Gerardo Furtado suggests, but it still won't show anything on the web page. So I am not running any server, I am just opening this html file from my local PC. Is that a problem?

Comment: Plainly, does the code work for you guys?

Comment: Friends, it works now. Please see my answer below. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to BJK, who helped me from Google D3.js group, I figured out the problem. I was not operating in the development environment. I was using local file system, which does not always work.

Here is the suggestion BJK sent me: "See https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki => section "local development"..."

After switch to the development environment, Mike Bostock (FYI, I remember his name as BossTalk, which is true for he talking data like a boss)'s code works perfectly.

Cheers.